# Knowing which criteria to seach by for Web Driver to select option from drop down menu

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to select a value in a drop down menu using WebDriver.  The selection I want to make is:

```
</option><option selected="selected" value="12345678~ Company Name ~123~123456789">         Company Name,    -- 759313        </option>
```

I have been using the code:

```
IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select"));
SelectElement selector2 = new SelectElement(element2);
```

I have been trying:

```
selector2.SelectByIndex(3); //it is the 3rd option in the list, starting my count at 1, not 0.
selector2.SelectByValue("12345678~ Company Name ~123~123456789");
selector2.SelectByText("         Company Name,    -- 759313        ");
```

After trying many times using these calls, I can't seem to get the selection to choose what I want it to, it throws back an error saying it can not find my selection.  I am assuming the spaces are what is giving me trouble or confusing me? I have tried both with and without spaces. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the select tag and all other options as well?

Comment: Print out the list of options (`.Options`) - do you see the one you want to select there?

Comment: @Saifur What I have posted are all the tags that are associated with this specific list...not much is provided with this site, unfortunately.

Comment: @alexce , I am sorry but I do not know how to do that.  Would you be able to send me a reference that would help me help you?

Comment: @Rinktacular I think you need to iterate over `selector2.Options` list and print out the values and texts.

Comment: @alexce Thanks, ill try that and get back to you.

Comment: @alexce if this helps, I discovered that this list is within a `<div id= dynamic_content>` tag...So when I select the drop down menu prior to this one, the page does some type of refresh? and the error I currently get is an "StaleElementReference" which I assume means it is due to it being "dynamic" and not always there?

Comment: You meant to say, after clicking on the div only, the select is visible

Comment: @Madhan Yes, thank you.  I am still fairly new to C# and HTML so the jargon isn't quite there yet :P

Comment: Ok.Then after clicking on the div wait till the dropdown is visible. and then select the values from dropdown.Refer [Webdriver wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and click on csharp button image to see c# code

Comment: @Madhan Awesome, i'll try just that.  I will get back with results.

Comment: @Madhan the main problem is that the values are not visible and they are filled as a result of what I choose for the first drop down.  To be put more simply...I am choosing from a list of 5 branches, and then selecting 5 sub-options from those branches, which are only visible after I choose the branch.

Comment: Select values from Firstdropdown..Wait for second dropdown to be visible [as the page might load] and then select values from second dropdown

Comment: @Madhan the second is always visible, it is just the values within the drop down that are not visible.

Comment: yes I know.After you select a value from firstdropdown wait for sometime[I think a page load will be called after this] use webdriverwait or put a sleep for 3 seconds or put a break point,,and then select the values from second

Comment: @madham understood.  Just wanted to make sure I gave you all the information that I could.  Thank you!

Comment: If you still face any issue post the code for two selects

Comment: @Madhan I Can now successfully pick values from the menu, it's just a matter of fixing my other options and I can finnaly run my loop.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Sure You can post what you've done to solve your problem as an answer

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with css:

```
.pulldown option[text*="12345678~ Company Name ~123~123456789"]
.pulldown option[value*="000759313"]
```

hope this works because i couldn't see complete description portion in the snapshot

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the XPath that contains my value, for reference]I found that my issue was having to wait for the values to be added to my drop down menu, which I previously was not waiting for. My solution is as followes:

```
if(TaxIdOwner == "TaxID1" || TaxIdOwner == "TaxID2")
                {
                    selector.SelectByText("Company based on Tax Id");
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                        {
                            //The XPath of the drop down menu that was not working for me
                            return d.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select"));
                        });
                    //Now that the web driver has waited, I can select the values I wanted.  
                    //I could only get these manual clicks to work, 
                    //WebElements didnt seem to want work for me, personally.
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).Click();
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select/option[3]")).Click();
                }
```

Comment: you should simplify your xpath, its very confusing and does not seem too reliable. can you share the source from DOM viewer such as firebug etc.?

Comment: @Karthik Sure no problem, I am new to firepath/firebug and XPath in general, so I am working on getting better paths.

Comment: @Karthik I posted a picture of my Fire path that I simplified for the value.  If you could recommend a better way to do this, I would be eager to learn!

Comment: Try to use this XPath: "//option[@class = 'pulldown']" :)

Comment: @nikita_em Thank you for the suggestion!  I put what you said into Firepath and it does not find anything, are you recommending that I use it like this?... `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@class = 'pulldown']")` ?

Comment: @nikita_em sorry, I kind of need more detail than you were expecting :P